# What's the song they are playing before Kaneki sees the news reports in season 2, episode 9?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

The track is played again at the end of the same episode when Kaneki is on the rooftop with Nishio and Tsukiyama.

Answer (score 2):

The song is called **Das zweite Kapitel**, which, according to Google Translate, means "the second chapter" in German. It is track 26 from the first disc of [Tokyo Ghoul Original Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263).